SwiftUI TabView phase shift in x direction with .rotationEffect
I want to make vertical TabView() like TikTok or YouTube.
But my code have some problems.

When FirstView().navigationDestination boots up, my NextView　behaves strangely.
In NextView(), when I swipe the screen in the x direction, NextView()'s screen phase shift in x direction(left).

struct FirstView: View {
  @State var isNextView = false
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        Button {
          isNextView.toggle()
        } label: {
          Text("go next page")
        }
      }
      .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isNextView, destination: {
        NextView()
          .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      })
    }
  }
}

struct NextView: View {
  let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
  let colors: [Color] = [Color.yellow, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.red, Color.pink]
  
  @State var selection: Int = 0
  @State var opacity = 1.0
  
  @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      ZStack {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
          ForEach(Array(0 ..< colors.count), id: \.self) { index in
            VStack {
              Rectangle()
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .foregroundColor(colors[index])
            }
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90), anchor: .center)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
          }
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
          .ignoresSafeArea()
          
        }
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90), anchor: .center)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .frame(width: height, height: width, alignment: .center)
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button {
              dismiss()
            } label: {
              Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
      .frame(width: width, height: height)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
  }
}

